# How to check if string contains only specific characters

Tags: php, regex

String: 10.0.3.1, 10.0.0.0/16,2001:db8:100:934b::3:1, 2001:db8:100:934b::/64
how to check this stirng? It can only contains `. , / :`. No other special characters is allowed.Just check if only have these 4 characters.

```
$string = '10.0.3.1, 10.0.0.0/16,2001:db8:100:934b::3:1, 2001:db8:100:934b::/64';
if (checkString($string)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}

function checkString(string $string) {
// how to check the string here?
}
```

my pattern not work

```
if (preg_match('/^(\.|\,|\/|\:)+$/', $string)) {
    var_dump('yes');
} else {
    var_dump('no');// return no
}

// I try this , and got an error
if (preg_match('/^(.*[^A-Za-z0-9.,/:]).*$/', $input)) {
    var_dump('yes');
} else {
    var_dump('no');
}
// preg_match(): Unknown modifier ':'
```

Comment: Use a character set, not alternation

Comment: Use `/[^\da-zA-Z.,\/:\s]/`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Or maybe use a negative lookahead: `^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9.,/:]).*$`

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to validate the structure of the data but just allow the characters so `,,,` is also valid?  `^[a-z0-9.,/: ]+$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9mvOYd/1/)

Comment: Change the delimiter from `/` to for example `~` like `if (preg_match('~^[a-z0-9.,/: ]+$~', $input)) {`

Comment: String can only contain these 4 characters, but can be repeated

Comment: Thanks you all for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting that you have space too in your string. Try replacing your function with this,

```
function checkString(string $string) {
    if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\/:, ]+$/', $string)) {
        var_dump('yes');
    } else {
        var_dump('no');// return no
    }
}
```